# Matplotlib hangs when run in a thread more than once

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I've got a script linked up to display as a heatmap, though I noticed it'd only save it once and then seem to stop saving. I dug into it a little more and found it actually never completed after it'd already run once. The script is finished, so I don't see why it should then fail. Just incase it was a problem with `matplotlib.pyplot`, I tried re-importing it at the start of the function, but it didn't do anything.

Here's some code to reproduce the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from threading import Thread

def plot(data, save_path):
    print 1
    #gets stuck here
    plt.imshow(data)
    print 2
    plt.colorbar()
    print 3
    plt.title('test')
    print 4
    plt.savefig(save_path)
    print 5
    plt.close()
    print 6

w, h = 640, 480
heatmap = np.zeros(h * w)
heatmap = heatmap.reshape((h, w))
tl = Thread(target=plot, args=(heatmap, 'C:/Users/Peter/Python/test.png'))
tl.start()
tl.join()
t2 = Thread(target=plot, args=(heatmap, 'C:/Users/Peter/Python/test.png'))
t2.start()
t2.join()
```

The result for this is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
```

The second one hangs the script on `plt.imshow(data, cmap=cm)`. How do I go about fixing this? The problem goes away if it's not threaded, but I'd prefer to keep it in a separate thread.

Comment: which version of `matplotlib` are you using and where are you running that code. Works fine for me on `mpl 2.0.0` running the code in `jupyter console` on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 on windows 10 and I assume it's the latest `matplotlib` as I installed it via pip last week. I'm running through IDLE, but I wouldn't have thought that'd make much of a difference

Comment: it might, what if you save that code into a file and just run it from the command prompt?

Comment: Same problem annoyingly. One thing I forgot to mention, the one non-pip thing I'm using is numpy so I could get mkl version (I needed scipy for the heatmap which needs that version), the file for that is called `numpy-1.11.3+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, I tried it with `mpl` 1.5.3 as well. I'm guessing it's something windows specific. You could always try installing python 3.6 with anaconda and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch for attempting to help anyway, I guess instead of saving a heatmap at certain intervals, I could just have a separate script to read the file and generate it, it's just a bit annoying as I more want to know why it's not working now haha :)

Comment: is the problem with the threads btw.? What if you just call `plot` twice in a row?

Comment: Thought I'd forgotten to add that part but it was the last sentence haha. Yeah it seems to work alright just calling `plot` twice in a row, it's just that the one particular function (`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`) combined with threads that seems to cause the problem, which is really weird, especially since I made sure the first thread had finished

Comment: that is strange indeed, also note that it's a problem with threads on _windows_ not on Linux